# Appending to Dataframe then shuffling by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe with some data. Something like

```
Time, Price
15:00  100
15:01  125
15:03  121
```

where time is the index of the dataframe. However, because the dataframe is missing some pieces of data like the row at 15:02 in my example above, I wrote an algorithm that finds the price for these missing rows. I now have a list of lists where each inner list is the time and price of missing data. For example, it could be

```
[[15:02,123]]
```

for this example. I plan to convert this list into a pandas dataframe, merge it back to the original dataframe and have it sorted by its index ( time ). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Convert the column to Datetime and sort. Stringify back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a dataframe out of your list with same columns.
Then use the function:

```
df = df.append(new_time_price_df,ignore_index=True)
```

And then use the method sort_values:

```
df = df.sort_values(‘Time’)
```

Now df is sorted properly!